# Server 2012 cannot print to network printer

Tags: windows-server-2012, network-printer

I am having an issue with server 2012 not being able to print.

**Issue**: Cannot print via TCP/IP from the server / Shared printing from clients.

I can connect printers over the network through TCP/IP on the server. It sees and connects to them. However, when I try to print a test page to them it just times out eventually and says it failed to print. The client PC's can print to the printers fine by using TCP/IP and connecting directly, but if I have them shared via the server, they cannot.

**Steps Taken:**

```
1. Restarted spooler on Server / Clients
2. Removed and reinstalled print drivers
3. Edited GPO to disable/enable print redirection (both made no difference)
4. Swapped out network switch
```

The reason I swapped out network switches is because the original switch would not allow TCP/IP printing from the clients when the printer was connected to them. I swapped to a different switch and it does allow TCP/IP printing.

I've checked firewall settings as well and don't notice anything that would prevent network printing, but it sure seems like it's somehow software related.

Comment: Symptom of a hostbased printer. Those are small so-ho printer without a formatter board to save on cost. The server compute the printout, so, the driver need admin right. Why it work locally but not shared. Trying another driver can work sometime. (like I used hp laserjet 4 on hplaserjet 1020 printer). (fyi, The laserjet4 driver is/was a standard for the pcl language, thus it work on almost anything). Let us know your printer model.

Comment: There are 2 price terms on the network it won't print to. A Kyocera 2560 and an hour 5500dtn. Both using universal print drivers. PS and PCL.

Comment: *printers, not price terms. I Was on my phone.

Comment: Also, this seems to be an intermittent issue. I left on Wed with printers not working. Came back Thursday, they worked almost all day (Started working over night) and now today they are back to not working again.

Comment: This is big printer model, they are not hostbased then. What kind of document they print ? I ask as some pdf can explode in size in the spooler if you don't have a postscript module. and I guess you have the latest driver installed too ?